# Windows XP Batch- IF EXIST FTP with Date Variable

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp

I am writing a quick batch to see if a file exists after executing an exe.

The file is created with a YYYYmmDDnumbernumbernumber.xml file name according to the current date.

How do I check for the file with a variable in the beginning? Here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off

set mydate=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%

if not exist "ftp://FTPsite/%mydate%*.xml" (echo nah) else (echo yea)

pause
```

Comment: `ftp://FTPsite/%mydate%*.xml` is this accessible with `if exist` ? I think you should use the ftp command for such check...

Comment: If exist is for files, not for ftp ressources.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot check existence of file on ftp server with `IF`.Instead try this after replacing the parameters that starts with **MY_**  :

```
!cls&echo off&setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
!cls&goto :ftp_end
open MY_FTP_SERVER
user MY_USER
pass MY_PASS
cd MY_REMOTE_DIR
ls . local.file
bye
:ftp_end

ftp -s:%0
set mydate=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
type local.file | findstr  /B "%mydate%" | find ".xml" && echo FILE IS OUT THERE && goto :skip_file_is_not_there
echo FILE IS NOT THERE
:skip_file_is_not_there
del local.file /q >nul
```