# Check existance of file on ftp

Tags: file, if-statement, batch-file, ftp

I want to check existence of file on ftp server using batch script.

Right now I have this code which saves it to ftp server:

```
@echo off
echo user prayagimages> d:\Images\ftpcmd1.dat
echo Pass123@>> d:\Images\ftpcmd1.dat

echo put d:\Images\%~1>> d:\Images\ftpcmd1.dat

echo quit>> d:\Images\ftpcmd1.dat
ftp -n -s:d:\Images\ftpcmd1.dat 118.139.173.227
del d:\Images\ftpcmd1.dat
```

Lets say if I post image.jpeg to server.
How do I check whether it is on the server or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This questions seem to request similar things:

> [To search for a file at FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247313/to-search-for-a-file-at-ftp)
>
> [Windows XP Batch- IF EXIST FTP with Date Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395133/windows-xp-batch-if-exist-ftp-with-date-variable)

Mainly the first one, but the second link has some useful info too.

Comment: Hello sir your first link is telling me to download file on local machine and then check whether it exist or not.

Comment: On second there is only one comment.... and seriously not able to understand... Subject line is--------------- you cannot check existence of file on ftp server with IF.Instead try this after replacing the parameters that starts with MY_ :

Comment: Can you please check my code... i am uploading single file to server through comman line...lets say which is imgFlower.jpeg, now i want to check whether this file went correctly or not...
Please help me with this..

Comment: I'm not used to ftp myself, Sorry.